# Change PowerShell parameters from dictionary to list of strings in C# method

Tags: c#

I have a method to call a PowerShell command along with parameters. I have defined it like this:

```cs
public string RunScript(string contentScript, Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> parameters)
    {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.AddScript(contentScript);
            ps.AddParameters(parameters);
```

My PowerShell command parameter is defined like this:

```cs
[Parameter]
public List<string> Properties { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

How do I change my `RunScript` method so that in parameters I take only the list of strings which is passed?

Comment: A Command Line is a string with spaces between the parameters.  So use string.Join(" ", parameters)

Comment: you have to display the contents of properties if you want help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a powershell, you are using this way: (for example)

```
PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-NetAdapter")
                                      .AddParameter("name", "Ethernet*")
                                      .AddParameter("ThrottleLimit", 5);
```

or you use a dictionary:

```
IDictionary parameters = new Dictionary<String, String>();
parameters.Add("name", "Ethernet*");
parameters.Add("ThrottleLimit", 5);

PowerShell shell = PowerShell.Create();
   shell.AddCommand("Get-NetAdapter");
   shell.AddParameters(parameters);
```

**.AddParameter** (for single creation) is not the same thing than **.AddParameters** (for multiple creation)

so with a correct list you could use: [AddParameters(IList)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameters?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)

so you have to adapt `string` to your case... I have never used that before but you could try:

```
public string RunScript(string contentScript, List<string> parameters)
    {
        using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.AddScript(contentScript);
            ps.AddParameters(parameters);
```

you use `properties` as arg

Comment: yes, so in parameters, i would just like the values to be passed as a list of strings

Comment: @ZZZSharePoint sorry i dont understand, you have to have properties and values to create prowershell...?please  display the content of properties..it will be easier to understand

Comment: ok, so in Dictionary I have values like this {[PnKey, {Pest}]}, {[Id, {r_001}]} and I am only interested in taking Pest and r_001 as my parameters and pass it to my Powershell

Comment: i have never used that, but you could try my fixed answer

Comment: i took the values.ToString and added it in a List<string> and passing this list as a parameter

Comment: if you dont mind, I have another question, I am getting powershell.create as null on debugging. any clue why?

Comment: i dont see why, you dont have other errors during compilation?

Comment: have you installed the right package on nuget? SDK reference assemblies for PowerShell version 3 or 4 or 5?  https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/

Comment: I have powerShell Statndard library of version5.1.1

Comment: also as I see I cant find ps.InvokeAsync in my intelligence

Answer (score 0):

to convert a dictionary to a list you can just iterate over the dictionary and add every item to a new list. If you need some information from the EntityProperty you can just access it like so:

```
List<string> parameterList = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in parameters)
{
     parameterList.Add(item.Key + item.Value.xyz);
}
```

To add every item as powershell parameter you can do something like this:

```
using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
{
     ps.AddScript( contentScript );

     foreach (var item in parameters)
     {
         ps.AddParameter(item.Key, item.Value.xyz);
     }
}
```

Comment: I just need the item Value in the parameter list ,If I write parameterList.Add(item.Value); I get error

Comment: yes, that is because the value in your dictionary if of type EntityProperty, while the list only accepts strings.

Comment: if I do value.StringValue?

Comment: yes, for example. As parameters you can only use strings, so you somehow need to convert your entityproperty to a string. I don't know about this type, so i cant help you with that